# php temporary file duration in centos

Tags: php

My application works on Ubuntu 14.04, but it doesn't on centos7.

It has a php (running in apache) and a service (an internal TCP server), after php gets a uploaded file from client, it will do something like the following

```
$src = $_FILES["userFile"]["tmp_name"];
//send TCP message with the $src to a service running on the same server
//wait for reply on the tcp connection
```

My service will wait for the tcp message and copy $src to a directory.  But on centos it complained something like "file /tmp/phpXZGTTn can't be found"

Wonder what's special about centos.  Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing php/Apache temporary files in /tmp – Systemd Private Temp

https://gryzli.info/2015/06/21/centos-7-missing-phpapache-temporary-files-in-tmp-systemd-private-temp/

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really helps.